# The cheapest Android 1.5 device

Tags: android

I am searching for the cheapest Android 1.5 device **suitable for developing on it**. As the emulator is too sluggish for my needs, I want a real device. 
Can you recommend any source where to get such an old device? I looked at eBay, but do not know which device to search for. Maybe you can recommend a list of Android 1.5 devices still available?

Comment: Why?  http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Comment: I know this chart. 10% is not negligible... Sure in the future it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HTC Dream/G1](http://www.htc.com/www/product/g1/overview.html) should be the cheapest option. I got mine for 88 bucks shipped from eBay... works perfectly.

Actually, the OS may be Android 1.6 (I can't remember as I eventually installed CyanogenMod) but it shouldn't matter since you can still write and test 1.5 applications on it.

Update: According to the phone's [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Dream), the official OS version is 1.6.

Comment: The g1 came with 1.5, but it's upgradeable to 1.6

Answer (score 1):

The most recent (and probably powerful) 1.5 device was probably the Dell Blaze, but it won't be easy to find. The G2 also came with 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

The G1 and MyTouch are the original android devices, and they shouldn't be too expensive on craigslist or ebay.

Answer (score 0):

Huawei devices are cheaper too, and suitable for development in most cases http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/productFamily.do?method=index&directoryId=2037&treeId=37

pd: check android models :p